# Displaying nodes from parent terms of user

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks, entities

I have a taxonomy with an organization of departments.

Organisation:

- Dept1

  - Subdept1
  - Subdept2
- Dept2

  - Subdept3
  - Subdept4

I have created a entity reference field, I use the same field with both users and nodes (message).

I want to send a message to only a part of the organisation, and the users are set to the sub-departments.

I have made a User-view with a contextual filter of the UID of the logged in user. If the user and the node have the same term, the nodes are listed.

But I need to be able to choose the above department, so one message can be sent to all sub-departments by choosing only their parrent term.

The block must be functional/visible on all pages.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'important_notifikations';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Vigtige Beskeder';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; 

$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Vigtige Beskeder';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'mere';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Submit';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Reset';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Sort';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['sort_asc_label'] = 'Up';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['sort_desc_label'] = 'Down';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';

$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_os2intra_physical_location_target_id_1']['id'] = 'field_os2intra_physical_location_target_id_1';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_os2intra_physical_location_target_id_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_os2intra_physical_location';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_os2intra_physical_location_target_id_1']['field'] = 'field_os2intra_physical_location_target_id';

$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['relationship'] = 'field_os2intra_physical_location_target_id_1';

$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['display'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['view_mode'] = 'teaser';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 0;

$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';

$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['exception']['title'] = 'All';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'message_notification' => 'message_notification',
);


$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
```

Comment: you can try writing a simple jquery script, which will select all the child items when parent item is selected. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I can not use a jquery script inside a view for a db request.